# How to create a gradient for the whole table in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've tried to add a gradient for a table like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct Row : Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var number: Float
    var id = UUID()
}
struct test: View {
    @Binding var data : [Row]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Table(data) {
                TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
                TableColumn("Value", value:
                                \.number.description)
                .width(50)
                
            }
            .background(RadialGradient(colors:[.white,.blue], center:UnitPoint(x:1,y:1), startRadius: 0.0, endRadius:20))
               
        }
    }
}

struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var items : [Row] = {
        var items = [Row]()
        let l = 0...100
        for i in 1...100 {
            let k = Float(Int.random(in:l))
            items.append(Row(name:"name \(i)", number: k))
        }
        return items
    }()
    static var previews: some View {
        test(data : .constant(items))
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I see a standard background:

[image]

It worked on other components. How can I apply a gradient for the table component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be much better off using a grid if you want such customization, but it is possible to use **.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)** to remove the background color and removing the alternating row backgrounds         **.tableStyle(.inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds: false))**

```
struct Row : Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var number: Float
    var id = UUID()
}
struct test: View {
    @Binding var data : [Row]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Table(data) {
                TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
                TableColumn("Value", value:
                                \.number.description)
                .width(50)
                
                
            }
            .tableStyle(.inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds: false))
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .background(RadialGradient(colors:[.white,.blue], center:UnitPoint(x:1,y:1), startRadius: 0.0, endRadius:20))
               
        }
    }
}
```